# Chrome-Remote-Desktop Issue

Tags: google-chrome

I routinely remote in to my Ubuntu desktop at my house via Chrome Remote Desktop from a variety of devices.  I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and Chrome Remote Desktop starting manifesting issues displaying the desktop.  All I get is a [black/blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIGCI.png) screen with an "X" for the cursor - from any client (Android pictured).  Has anyone ran into this issue, and what is the cause/fix?

Comment: What do you mean by `CRD`?

Comment: Chrome-Remote-Desktop (CRD)

Comment: Related: https://medium.com/@vsimon/how-to-install-chrome-remote-desktop-on-ubuntu-18-04-52d99980d83e

Comment: I have exactly the same problem in Ubuntu 20.04.